# Sybase. Error al Convertir datos de Varchar a Int

Tags: sql, sybase

buen día necesito de su ayuda tengo el siguiente problema
tengo una sintaxis de base de datos como la siguiente

```
     declare @num int
     declare @numero int
     declare @variable1 int
     declare @variable2 int
     declare @texto1 varchar(18)

     set @numero = @num
     set @texto1 = convert(varchar(11),@numero)
     set @variable1 = right(@texto1,4)
     set @variable2 = left(@texto1, len(@texto1)-4)

     select @variable1
     select @variable2
```

pero me da el error
Implicit conversion from datatype 'VARCHAR' to 'INT' is not allowed. use the convert function to run this query

Comment: En esa query tienes un error de paréntesis en `convert(varchar(11,@numero)` debería de ser `convert(varchar(11),@numero)`

Comment: si me confundí cuando redacte el problema pero si lo tengo en mi código

Comment: Hola Junion, veo que "@numero" toma el valor de "@num" pero este no tiene ningún valor!